# Can't create a cloud object storage on a lite account in IBM Cloud

Tags: cloud-object-storage

I'm unable to create a cloud object storage plan on my lite account. Everything is fine but it keeps on bringing this error.

> [409, Conflict] The account already has an instance created with the
> Lite plan.
>
> Transaction ID: 0d6c5ad8f82f401f979876fca94f5254:59967a3beae87f54

what could be the issue.